# AngularJS parse ping response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a AngularJS based SPA which can send ping request over websocket to a server. I would like to parse ping responses coming from server from the detailed response. i.e I would like to know if the ping were successful or failed with the count for each success/fail (I just want the information in bold in the response below). One more thing, I would like to achieve is that in case of failure, show some RED light with numbers of failed pings/out of total sent and in case of success show Green light with numbers of successful pings/out of total sent. **Please take a look at pingController.js and pingController.html.**
Here is my plunk.[Send ping command to server](http://plnkr.co/edit/xlU3D9?p=info)

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index ">
 {{message}}
</div>
```

**I believe I created and tried the filter for angularJS after going through several links, I haven't figured the right way of doing this.**

```
SmartCartApp.filter('parseResponse', function () {
  // function to invoke by Angular each time
  // Angular passes in the `items` which is our Array
  return function (messages) {
    // Create a new Array
    var filtered = [];
    // loop through existing Array
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      var message = messages[i];
      var res = message.match(/Success/g); //this filters messages which has Success string in it. Looks like I need to create a multiple of those to just get Success/Failure
      if(res !==null)
      {
         filtered.push(message);
      }

    }
      return filtered;
  };
});
```

The server sends responds based on the success/failure to my SPA.
Here are what responses looks like.

Failure:

NIC[;]0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000[,]0,0,0,0,0,0[,]0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.001479,0.000000[,]0,0,0,0,0,0[/] 
03/06/2017 17:43:28.0251[;]Ping[;]Status[;] **Ping to www.google.com** : Resolved Addresses: 216.239.50.80 **Total Sent: 22 Total Success: 0 Total Errors: 22** Total Timed Out: 0 Minimum RTT(ms): 0 Maximum RTT(ms): 0 Average RTT(ms): 0.00[/] 
03/06/2017 17:43:28.0251[;]Ping[;]Ping Result[;]www.google.com[,]False[,]10[,]1[,]3[,]0[,]216.239.50.80[,]TtlExpired[,]True[,]TtlExpired[/] 
03/06/2017 17:43:28.0813[;]Ping[;]Running[;]FALSE[/] 
03/06/2017 17:43:28.1874[;]Traffic[;]Total Traffic[;]0.002960[,]0[,]0.003569[,]0[,]2.057E+09[,]ALL[/]

Success: 
03/06/2017 17:48:45.2265[;]Traffic[;]Traffic by NIC[;]0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000[,]0,0,0,0,0,0[,]0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000732,0.000000[,]0,0,0,0,0,0[/] 
03/06/2017 17:48:45.3019[;]Ping[;]Status[;] **Ping to www.ibm.com** : Resolved Addresses: 173.223.238.158 **Total Sent: 9 Total Success: 9 Total Errors: 0** Total Timed Out: 0 Minimum RTT(ms): 8 Maximum RTT(ms): 14 Average RTT(ms): 10.33[/] 
03/06/2017 17:48:45.3031[;]Ping[;]Ping Result[;]www.ibm.com[,]False[,]10[,]1[,]3[,]9[,]173.223.238.158[,]Success[,]False[,]None[/] 
03/06/2017 17:48:46.2251[;]Traffic[;]Total Traffic[;]0.002205[,]0[,]0.005805[,]0[,]2.057E+09[,]ALL[/] 
03/06/2017 17:48:46.2251[;]Traffic[;]Traffic by NIC[;]0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.002205,0.000000[,]0,0,0,0,0,0[,]0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.005805,0.000000[,]0,0,0,0,0,0[/] 
03/06/2017 17:48:47.2304[;]Traffic[;]Total Traffic[;]0.000867[,]0[,]0.002704[,]0[,]2.057E+09[,]ALL[/] 
03/06/2017 17:48:47.2304[;]Traffic[;]Traffic by

Comment: I added the filter shown in the original post above but it still doesn't provide me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I found this can be done multiple ways. 
1) The easiest was using match property of a string in JavaScript. 
I also learned that this can be done using angular filter or factory/service.
Here is what I implemented using service.

```
myApp.service('ParseMessageService', function() {
  this.myFunc = function(message) {

    var res = message.match(/Success/g);

    if (res !== null) {
      //console.log(res);
      TSent = message.match(/Total Sent: (\d+)/);
      if (TSent) {
        sent = TSent[1];
        //parsedMsg.push(TSent[1]);
       //console.log(TSent[1]); //replace with $scope and display on Gui
      }
      TSucc = message.match(/Total Success: (\d+)/);
      if (TSucc) {
        succ = TSucc[1];
        //parsedMsg.push(TSucc[1]);
       // console.log(TSucc[1]); //replace with $scope and display on Gui
      }
      TErr = message.match(/Total Errors: (\d+)/);
      if (TErr) {
        err = TErr[1];
        //parsedMsg.push(TErr[1]);
        //console.log(TErr[1]); //replace with $scope and display on Gui
      }

    }
  }
```